# upload csv to server from local system using php

Tags: php, csv, ftp

```
<?php

// FTP access parameters
$source_ftp_server = 'ftp://uk9.siteground.eu';
$source_ftp_user_name = 'xyz';
$source_ftp_user_pass = 'abc';

// file to move:
$local_file = '/Users/Swayam/Desktop/Test.csv';
$remote_file = '/home/c10mill2/public_html/edtopiadb/Test.csv';

$fp = fopen($local_file, 'r');
$conn_id = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);
$ret = ftp_nb_fput($conn_id, $remote_file, $fp, FTP_BINARY);
while ($ret == FTP_MOREDATA) {
       // Establish a new connection to FTP server
    if(!isset($conn_id2)) {
        $conn_id2 = ftp_connect($source_ftp_server);
        $login_result2 = ftp_login($conn_id2, $source_ftp_user_name, $source_ftp_user_pass);
    }

       // Retreive size of uploaded file.
    if(isset($conn_id2)) {
        clearstatcache(); // <- this must be included!!
        $remote_file_size = ftp_size($conn_id2, $remote_file);
    }

       // Calculate upload progress
    $local_file_size  = filesize($local_file);
    if (isset($remote_file_size) && $remote_file_size > 0 ){
        $i = ($remote_file_size/$local_file_size)*100;
                printf("%d%% uploaded<br>", $i);
                flush();

    }
    $ret = ftp_nb_continue($conn_id);

}


if ($ret != FTP_FINISHED) {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'><b>There was an error uploading the      file...</b></span><br>";
    exit(1);
}
 else {
     echo "<br>Files successfully uploaded!<br><br>";
 }

fclose($fp);
```

Pls help me with the code to get it working.
When i execute this code i get a error -

```
Warning: ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /Users/Swayam/Desktop/sample.php on line 14
Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Swayam/Desktop/sample.php on line 15
Warning: ftp_nb_fput() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Swayam/Desktop/sample.php on line 16
<span style='color:red;'><b>There was an error uploading the file...</b></span><br>
```

Comment: `$source_ftp_server = 'ftp://uk9.siteground.eu';` should be  `$source_ftp_server = 'uk9.siteground.eu';`

Comment: Are you going to upload CVS or Parse CSV than save to database ?

Comment: @blackxel Still same issue, Warning: ftp_nb_fput(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /Users/Swayam/Desktop/sample.php on line 16
<span style='color:red;'><b>There was an error uploading the file...</b></span><br>

Comment: @ganaa I just want to upload my csv file from local system to the server file system